# Ошибка при создании метки: вы пытаетесь создать метку Xs, хотя уже существует метка X

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки

библиотека прекрасная, а тега для нее нет
добавил скрин с доказательством невозможности создания тега:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Логично, что теги должны добавлять только тогда, когда ими пользуются. Если тега ещё не существует, значит его не использовали в вопросе

Comment: Нет вопросов - нету тега.

Comment: я только что пытался, но мне говорит, что тега нет и вы не можете его юзать

Comment: за что минусы, мне могу понять

Comment: Ща бы для каждого более-мене популярного npm пакета тег добавлять.  "В первый день нашей ежегодной фронтенд конференции мы просто зачитываем список популярных библиотек появившихся с прошлогодней фронтенд конференции"

Comment: @Nikolay на мете нет репутации. Семантика минусов на мете отличается от основного сайта - здесь она просто "согласен с предложением"/"не согласен с предложением". Не обижайтесь.

Comment: @Nikolay, есть какой-то порог репутации для создания новых меток чтобы новички не плодили.

Comment: @Nikolay А можете предоставить скрин экрана, где у Вас возникает проблема с добавлением метки? Судя по [привилегиям](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) возможность создавать метки доступна с 300 баллов репутации

Comment: Это прикол из английского SO, что `s` говорит о множественном числе. Отсюда и ограничения.

Comment: @alexolut и что делать?)) сказано написать сюда, я и написал

Comment: @Nikolay всё правильно сделали. Дяди будут думать и через 6-8 недель дадут ответ. Наверное.

Comment: создал метку, поставил на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/698034

Comment: @PashaPash а месяца через два сожжём за ненадобностью :)

Comment: @Nikolay. Старайтесь всегда прикладывать улики. Одной картинки хватило, чтобы повернуть ситуацию в вашу пользу)

Comment: @EgorTrutnev буду знать, спасибо)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский через какое-то время метка сама пропадет, если не появится второй вопрос.

Comment: @alexolut, а есть возможноть просклонять название мета-сайта на той надписи?

Comment: @mymedia может да, а может и нет. В транзифексе есть две строки, в одной можно поменять, в другой нет. Вторая новее, так что вероятнее всего поменять нельзя, если используется более новая строка.

Answer (score 2):

Невозможность создать метку вида `Xs` при наличии метки `X` возникает из-за логики с английского Stack Overflow. Т.к. суффикс `s` говорит о множественном числе, и эта защита была реализована для исключения (случайного) создания групп парных меток в единственном и множественном числах. К "Stack Overflow на русском" данное правило, конечно же, не должно применяться. Но я не уверен, можно ли его настраивать отдельно для каждого сайта. Модератор может создать такую метку при желании. Что, собственно, и было сделано.

По результатам конкретной проблемы из [комментария](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5652/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-xs-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5?noredirect=1#comment21507_5652) PashaPash ♦:

> создал метку, поставил на ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/698034

Comment: *К "Stack Overflow на русском" данное правило, конечно же, не должно применяться* – не был бы так уверен, язык индустрии английский, и к нам неминуемо будут вытекать английские термины. Лучше оставить.

Comment: @D-side не думаю, что кто-то из русскоязычных участников будет осознанно пытаться добавлять метки множественного английского числа при существующей метке в единственном числе. Но от исключения правила профита тоже будет не много, т.к. ситуация вида `tar` → `tars` довольна редка. А на русские множественные и единственные числа у нас обычно заводятся синонимы.

Comment: От исключения для этого сайта тоже профита немного. С уважением, ИО лени команды SE :)

Comment: @D-side вот я и говорю про **этот** сайт. Но зато так мы узнали о наличии правила на enSO :)